# Is editing being abused?

Tags: discussion, editing

I never noticed this practice on *stackoverflow* or *serverfault*, but I noticed on *superuser* that some users will answer a question if a placeholder that either barely or does not answer the question it was in response to. Several minutes later, the user will then edit their post to answer the question and incorporate other answers. This seems like a blatant abuse of the system.

I understand that [The Fastest Guns in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/is-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-solved) is considered solved, but doesn't this kind of abuse seem like a response to at least the perception that early posts are accepted and up voted more often?

In short, is it an abuse of the system to post placeholder answers to a question and if so what can be done about it?

Comment: An edit abuse question that doesn't appear to be about **He Who Shall Not Be Named**?  It's like I've stepped into an alternate universe.

Comment: Why would Voldemort have any reason to be on SO? He's not programming related.

Comment: @Welbog: yeah, that's why they banished him to SuperUser...

Comment: I think Voldemort was "He Who Must Not Be Named", so they are talking about a different nameless horror.

Answer (score 8):

I think it is an abuse of the system to post something that is purely a placeholder and has no content or attempt at an answer whatsoever. However, if its partial answer, or an answer without supporting code/links I think that is acceptable. It potentially still helps the OP faster, and has meaningful content. While still allowing the answerer to update the content to a more complete version.

Comment: I often post the first sketch of the code first, then edit to make cleaner (i.e. idented) code and only then provide full answer. First steps to just satisfy this user this time, further steps to make better answer for ones who will find it in future.

Answer (score 7):

It is not abuse, and is actually desirable.

We like faster answers on the sites and as long as the answer was on topic and had at least something of content in it, there is nothing wrong with fleshing it out later.

It is actually one of the reasons why there is a time delay on when the revision history picks up on edits.

This answer is actually an example of this by the way.

Comment: So if you asked a question that was say "How are pencils made?" and I answered "With wood!" then waited until there were 5 other answers then copied them, that would be desirable?

Comment: @David: If the answer is right, who cares?

Comment: @David: Actually, yes, but only to a certain extent. The top voted answer usually does become a collection of several other posts whether intentional or not.

Comment: @Pesto: It's a problem because it's frustrating to see well thought out answers being copied by users who are simply throwing placeholders to obtain a high listing on the page. The point system is in place to provide a form of incentive and currency to crowd moderation. When there's a blatant abuse of that system that is unchecked, I feel that it reduces the worth of the system as a whole because it reduces the incentive to answer questions.

Comment: @David: So basically you are just mad at the FGITW problem?

Comment: @Rich: That seems a bit odd to me as well, because it's circumventing a valuable feature -- the ranking of good suggestions. By combining all the answers into one single post, you loose the ability to rank individual components of that answer, hence a lot of the granularity that was originally in the system.

Comment: @Rich: If you want to view it as such, sure, but I think I'll graciously bow out of this conversation then.

Comment: @David: This site is not only about getting rep, like you are implying. This site is about creating a repository of questions and answers with the answers right on top, under the question.

Comment: @Rich B: I don't think David was implying that the site is "only" about getting rep.  After all, David was not the one to identify and name the so-called FGITW problem.  He simply identified a special case of that problem (placeholders) and asked whether it should be given extra consideration.  The idea that it is a problem, though, did not originate with and is certainly not unique to David Ma.

Comment: @Rich: I don't think you're understanding my argument. These sites allows users to have their questions answered with quality responses. Quality responses are solicited from the community. To moderate, augment, encourage, and reward responses, a reputation system is in place. If this reputation system is abused, then it reduces the worth of that auxiliary. If we're to believe that these supporting systems actually have worth, that they increase the quality of answers, then it stands to reason that abuse the system will reduce the quality of answers.

Comment: @David: But again, you keep calling it 'abuse'. It is not abuse. It is encouraged. Jeff Atwood has said before that his intentions were that a quick way to pick up rep would be to consolidate a bunch of less complete answers into your own. This is how the system works.

Comment: @David Ma: but you're not talking about abuse that results in lower-quality answers. You're talking about a practice that actively builds *higher* -quality answers, by incorporating the best parts of disparate answers into a single, (hopefully-) coherent reply. That's *a good thing* !

Comment: @Shog9: My contention is that it produces an overall decrease in answer quality because there is less incentive to post good responses, even if compound answers are superior overall (which I don't agree on).

Comment: @David: If that were the case, shouldn't we be seeing this reduced quality by now?

Comment: @David Ma: all things being equal, if you post the most helpful, comprehensive and attractive answer, you'll get the votes. That the system allows... and to an extent, rewards - the compilation of somewhat-helpful, partial answers into a complete package only serves to further promote a result that should be seen as inevitable. Think about it: the vast majority of information on these sites **already exists** : it's out there, *somewhere* ; we're just bringing it together. The person to make the best use of his sources - whether they be books, websites, or adjacent answers - "wins".

Comment: @Rich: I really don't think such demands can be easily answered. Say the quality of posts can be quantified via a monotonically increasing function over time. Can this "quality" function be produced through the addition of several functions where at least one of these functions is not monotonically increasing? Obviously. What we're discussing is somewhat ethereal in nature. It's difficult to quantify those who choose not to contribute or leave the community out of frustration.

Comment: @Rich: The problem I'm discussing has similar results as FGITW, and I don't think anyone here feels that the FGITW problem was a good thing -- we only disagree on whether it was adequately addressed or not. I believe there is a particular weakness related to FGITW that I feel has not been addressed.

Comment: @David: I think navel gazing solves nothing. This is all by design, and is working as expected. When we see an issue, it might need to be addressed. Currently, I see no issue.

Comment: If somebody has just copied other answers then it's up to people to comment saying so.. and down to the OP to not be stupid enough to accept it. One can always comment and say one answer is better than another. or that everything a person has said has been said earlier by others.

Answer (score 2):

This does happen on SO, so I can only assume it does on SF as well.

I don't think it can ever be stopped, unless a ban is put on editing posts within a certain time period. However, that would (I feel) cause more problems than it solves as an incorrect post could attract multiple down-votes in that period.

You might be noticing it now because SU is so new. It could settle down in a few days.